# historical result of SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, pagination

I want to query a large number of rows and displayed to the user, however the user will see only for example 10 rows and I will use LIMIT and OFFSET, he will press 'next' button in the user interface and the next 10 rows will be fetched.

The database will be updated all the time, is there any way to guarantee that the user will see the data of the next 10 rows as they were in the first select, so any changes in the data will not be reflected if he choose to see the next 10 rows of result.

This is like using SELECT statement as a snapshot of the past, any subsequent updates after the first SELECT will not be visible for the subsequent SELECT LIMIT OFFSET.

Comment: What you want is called *pagination*

Answer (score 1):

You can use cursors, example:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test(id int primary key);
insert into test 
select i from generate_series(1, 50) i;

declare cur cursor with hold for
select * from test order by id;

move absolute 0 cur; -- get 1st page
fetch 5 cur;

 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
(5 rows)

truncate test;

move absolute 5 cur; -- get 2nd page
fetch 5 cur; -- works even though the table is already empty

 id 
----
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
(5 rows)

close cur;
```

Note that it is rather expensive solution. A declared cursor creates a temporary table with a complete result set (a snapshot). This can cause significant server load. Personally I would rather search for alternative approaches (with dynamic results).

Read the documentation: [DECLARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html), [FETCH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-fetch.html).

Comment: performance is very important, it will work as a concept, but not as a practical way.

Comment: If you want a snapshot, practically you have no alternatives. Once created, the cursor will be really fast. The main cost is to create a temporary table. Alternativelly you can maintain the paging on client side, but this requires sending the whole result to the client.